# Am I approaching concurrency right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction about whether or not I am using concurrency correctly. I find that currently, the code is very unwieldy and almost unintuitive. For the purposes of my demonstration, please note the CoreData architecture is as described by Marcus Zarra in his article http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/. Since the operation could take a very long time, I want this entire process to be done in a background thread.

```
 NSManagedContext *context = [[NSManagedContext alloc] initWithConcurrency:NSPrivateConcurrencyQueue];
 context.parentContext = [[CoreDataController sharedDispatch] managedObjectContext];
 [context performBlock: ^{
 NSManagedObject *someManagedObject = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] firstObject];
 NSString *resultFromLongOperation = [self someLongOperation:someManagedObject];
 [self doSomething];
 BOOL anotherResultFromLongOperation = [self aDifferentLongOperation:someManagedObject];
 }];
```

So from this short example, we can see that I am manipulating the variable someManagedObject, which is of NSManagedObject type and therefore must be used in a performBlock/performBlockAndWait as prescribed by Apple. Should I be passing in the context into someLongOperation and aDifferentLongOperation? If I don't, wouldn't that mean I would have to create another child context and do whatever the function does inside a performBlock/performBlockAndWait and return the result with a __block type? What about in the event if the result of someLongOperation affects the response of aDifferentLongOperation? Am I still structuring my code properly for a situation like this?

Thanks very much in advanced!

Comment: This kind of code is surely ugly but it's dense. Another approach would be to use GCD which makes sense if you have a lot of complex things running side by side.

Comment: GCD would still dispatch a separate thread, thus violating the one context/thread rule set by Apple. However, even if that was allowed, how does that solve my problem? I would still need to use __block variable types to retrieve the response?

Comment: You can create a sequential queue and have one context for that queue. To communicate safely between threads, you pass IDs around. So thread 1 does a search operation, finds three objects, these objects cannot be used on another thread safely, but you can pass their IDs safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this same issue not long ago.

I've looked for best practice scenarios and found that:

- You indeed, as you stated, shouldn't violate the one context/thread rule set by Apple.
- You should normally use completion blocks or notifications with long running operations, whether it's for not making the UI freeze, or just for code clarity.
- When you use a completion block, you can create a child context in your long running operation function (someLongOperation) and do whatever you want with it.
- If your result is a NSString, then you shouldn't have a problem, because it's not a NSManagedObject and it not bound to any one context.
- If you result is a NSManagedObject, then you should pass its NSManagedObjectID to the completion block (with `[managedObject objectID]` method).
- You can use the context's method `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` in case you created a new entity and it doesn't have an object ID yet.

Basically, you can use the same context for every long running operation if they all use the same thread. In my case they don't necessarily so I'm creating a new child context for every long running operation just to be sure (creating a new child context is a very fast operation so performance isn't an issue)